# Multiple flex/bison parsers

Tags: yacc, bison, lex, parser-generator

What is the best way to handle multiple Flex/Bison parsers inside a project?

I wrote a parser and now I need a second one in the same project. So far in the third section of `parser1.y` I inserted the `main(..)` method and called `yyparse` from there.

What I want to obtain is having two different parsers (`parser1.y` and `parser2.y`) and be able to use them from an external function (let's assume `main` in `main.cpp`).

Which precautions should I use to export `yyparse` functions outside `.y` files and how should I handle two parsers?

PS. I'm using g++ to compile but not the C++ versions of Flex and Bison and I would like to keep it this way (so avoiding encapsulating the parser inside an object).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that Bison provides the '-p zz' option to prefix symbols with 'zz' instead of 'yy'.

Similarly, Flex provides the '-P zz' option to prefix symbols with 'zz' instead of 'yy'.  It uses '-p' for performance reporting.  'Tis a pity they are not consistent with each other.

Answer (score 12):

In addition to Leffler's answer, I'd like to provide another approach here:

In the `.lex` file you could use `%option prefix="PREFIX"`, and in the `.y` file you could use `%define api.prefix PREFIX`, which does the same thing as passing `-p PREFIX` to Bison and `-P PREFIX` to Flex.

Notice after the overriding of the default prefix `yy`, you can access internal names via BOTH the original `yy*` and your overridden `PREFIX*`, while obviously for external names you MUST use your `PREFIX*` to access them.

Comment: Note that in modern bison versions you need to do `%define api.prefix {PREFIX}` or you get a warning

Answer (score 6):

If you use Bison 3.0 or better, then have a look at `%define api.prefix {foo_}`, which replaces all `yy` and `YY` prefixes with `foo_` and `FOO_`.

See the [Documentation about Multiple Parsers](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Multiple-Parsers.html#Multiple-Parsers).

Between Bison 2.6 and 3.0, there used to be no braces: `%define api.prefix foo_`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what was already stated, if you use a '%define api.prefix {PREFIX}' it will also rename yytext && yyparse to PREFIXtext and PREFIXparse. Don't forget the {} around the prefix !
 
The same applies to '%option prefix="PREFIX"' in lex, your lexer will be renamed to PREFIXlex.

Answer (score 0):

The api.prefix variable is not working for me anymore (it's producing a compilation error)

```
%define api.prefix {PREFIX}
```

I had to use the following syntax

```
%name-prefix="PREFIX"
```

Comment: Uh ... the one you had to use is actually the older way and is obsolete. The manual explicitly states this even.